# “De” ou “des” avant un adjectif

Tags: grammaire, articles, déterminants

J'ai l'habitude d'entendre

> Elle a de beaux yeux/de beaux cheveux

Par conséquent, j'ai cru comprendre que la règle devait être:

Pour ajouter un adjectif pour qualifier **yeux** dans *Elle a des yeux* entre l'article indéfini et le nom (yeux), il faut remplacer *des* par *de*

Ce qui n'a pas l'air d'être correct étant donné l'extrait d'[article suivant](http://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/monde/%C2%ABfake-news%C2%BB-facebook-et-google-accus%C3%A9s-de-n%C3%A9gligence-apr%C3%A8s-la-tuerie-de-las-vegas/ar-AAsQyJB?li=BBoJIji):

> Les deux plateformes en ligne ont relayé automatiquement DES fausses informations…

Si mon raisonnement était bon, l'extrait deviendrait:

> relayé automatiquement DE fausses informations…

Quelle est la/les règle(s)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il manque une notion dans ton raisonnement, à savoir le fait qu'un nom se trouve derrière l'adjectif.

**Règle théorique**

Comme on peut le voir [ici](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11349.php),

> Même si au pluriel, l'article partitif est *des*, si un adjectif épithète est placé devant le nom dans la langue écrite ou dans la langue orale soignée, on le remplace par *de*.

La structure est la suivante :
**DE + adjectif épithète + nom pluriel**

Par exemple, *Il fréquente de grands restaurants !*

Il existe cependant une exception, **qui est sujette à débat car [il semblerait qu'elle soit toujours grammaticalement incorrecte](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-he-has-good-reflexes.344327/#post-2049225)**, bien qu'à l'oral on l'emploie très souvent :

> Lorsque l'épithète et le nom forment une sorte de nom composé, on maintient *des*.

On obtient alors la structure : **DES + nom composé** (d'un nom simple et d'un adjectif)

À titre personnel, je pense que cette exception peut être soumise à interprétation, selon si l'on considère l'adjectif et le nom comme un nom composé ou pas. Cela peut également dépendre de si l'on souhaite mettre l'accent sur l'adjectif qui qualifie le nom.

Par exemple, « Il y a des petites filles dans la rue » n'insiste sur aucun attribut en particulier. En revanche, je pense que la phrase « Il y a de petites filles dans la rue » est également correcte si l'on souhaite insister sur la petite taille des filles.

Je pense que l'extrait *des fausses informations* entre dans ce cas de figure, où l'on considère que « fausses informations » est un nom composé. C'est pour cela que l'auteur a laissé « des » et non « de ».

**Langue orale usuelle**

Il arrive souvent que cette règle ne soit pas respectée à l'oral, et cela a tendance à être reproduit à l'écrit pour cette raison.

Comment: Mais il y a également une notion de "dénombrabilité" ! est-ce qu'on peut compter, ou non, tel ou tel concept !