# Des courts textes ou de courts textes?

Tags: articles

Si je veux poser une question, est-ce que c'est correct de dire

"Quels outils utiliser pour écrire un livre ou des courts textes?" ou

"Quels outils utiliser pour écrire un livre ou de courts textes?"

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/9789/17649 https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27411/17649

Answer (score 2):

L'article indéfini *de* sera utilisé ici :

> Quels outils utiliser pour écrire un livre ou **de** courts textes ?

et *des* si l'adjectif *courts* est placé après :

> Quels outils utiliser pour écrire un livre ou **des** textes courts ?

Comment: Sorry for the rudimentary question here, but In French is it fine to write "Quels outils utiliser"? I think it means "which tools to use", but there is neither a preposition (like *à*; or something equavalent to *to* in English) nor verb conjugation.

Comment: @Blaszard The sentence as written is fine. The verb doesn't need to be conjugated, just like with your correct English translation *which tools to use*. While in that case the preposition *to* is required before an English infinitive, there is no such requirement in French. There are however cases where *de* plays the same role as *to* like in *j'ai besoin d'utiliser un outil* : "I need to use a tool".